# Change stroke and fill on custom button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a template for come media player controls using polygons and rectangles in a WPF application written in C#.  I have three 'states' for the button.

```
Idle = stroke=Black; Fill=Black
MouseOver = stroke=White; Fill=Black
MouseDown/Disabled = Stroke=black; fill=White
```

I have the first two working but I cannot get the last.  Thus far I have the following code:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Canvas Height="24" Width="18">
                <Polygon x:Name="play" Points="2,0 18,9 2,18" Fill="Black" Canvas.Top="2"/>
            </Canvas>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="play" Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="play" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

PlayCommand:

```
public class PlayCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;
    public PlayCommand(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return !_viewModel.IsPlaying;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.Play(); // sets IsPlaying to true
    }
}
```

ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public bool IsPlaying
 {
     get {return _isPlaying; }
     private set
     {
         if (value != _isPlaying)
         {
             _isPlaying = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsPlaying"));
         }
     }
 }
```

When I attempt to build out Triggers that look at IsEnabled to set the stroke and fill, they seem to be never fired even though the button is disabled.  Any advice?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

App.xaml.cs

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow(config);
        main.Show();
    }
```

ViewModel Constructor:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(Configuration config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        _player = new MediaPlayerMock();
        _player.StatusChanged += _player_StatusChanged;
        PlayCommand = new PlayCommand(this);
        StopCommand = new StopCommand(this);

    }

    public ICommand PlayCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand StopCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: please show how you wrote a trigger for IsEnabled. `<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"><Setter TargetName="play" Property="Fill" Value="White"/><Setter TargetName="play" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/></Trigger>` works fine for me

Comment: I modified the XAML to look exactly like your changes @ASh.  It did nothing.  I also removed the initial stroke and fill from the polygon.  No dice.

Comment: Yes @Clemens, I just did not include that in the question for expediency.  I am initializing and setting the data context of the XAML during construction.  Then, the CanExecute is calling the IsPlaying to determine if the button should be disabled or not.

Comment: @Clemens, I have edited the question to include everything that should tie it together for you.  If you look at the PlayCommand's CanExecute, you will see a reference to IsPlaying which gets modified during the Play method in the ViewModel (for example)

Comment: @Clemens, I want the polygon fill and stroke to change when IsEnabled is True vs when False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VisualState Manager can also be used in such situations. Visual States encapsulate all that for you and give you the possibility to change the control based on **states** instead of **transitions**. That's a (maybe important) difference.

TL;DR at the bottom btw.

When using data triggers or triggers in general you will gain the benefit of using whichever property and event you want to trigger different styles. But you only have access to those transitions.

States on the contrary work on, well, states. The difference is quite straightforward. Transitions have no information on states. What happens if you mouse over a readonly textbox control? Right, it starts the hovering changes altough hovering is not aplicable here as the textbox is not editable. States can take care of that as they only change when all conditions are met. The triggers will change on the red dotted line whereas states won't.

[image: Example of a state machine for demonstration purposes]

Beside getting consistent states instead of transitions you also gain more benefits. You can also access the focused state of a control or the validation state, which is a mechanism supplied by dependency properties.

To find out which one you want you can look at what you want to change and when. If you want a mouse up over the control to result in a different result than just hovering without clicking previously, transitions are what you are looking for. If you just want to visually encode the particular resulting states of the control, use the VisualStateManager instead if possible.

**TL;DR:** Triggers and Visual States are different and behave different. You might want to evaluate which one you need. Visual States are defined in the template only, which can be a downside for using them. You also need to use storyboards but with a duration of zero they also get applied instantly. [A list of all states for a button can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates). For example a flat button could be created as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Opacity="0." x:Name="Overlay" />
            <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity="0." x:Name="OverlayDark" />
            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState.Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="OverlayDark"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                        <VisualState.Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState.Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="OverlayDark"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Changed this to the answer because I ended up going this route in a round-about way.  I opened the solution in Blend and used the controls there to change the states and then bound the `IsEnabled` to the `IsPlaying` property.

Answer (score 1):

You should fire the `CanExecuteChanged` event when the view model's `IsPlaying` property changes:

```
public class PlayCommand : ICommand
{
    ...
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.Play();
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you may have a DataTrigger on `IsPlaying` instead of a Trigger on `IsEnabled`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="False">
    <Setter ... />                    
</DataTrigger>
```